# DynDNS configuration - second to last packet is timed out during tracert

Tags: isp, dynamic-dns, traceroute

I have a NAS in a separate location which I connect into through a DynDNS domain I got for it. When I tracert to that DynDNS name, the following comes up:

```
1     3 ms     2 ms    <1 ms  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home [192.168.1.1]
2     4 ms     4 ms     4 ms  L***.CITY-VFTTP-***.verizon-gni.net [**.***.**.***]
3     5 ms    11 ms    11 ms  G*-*-*-*.CITY-LCR-**.verizon-gni.net [***.***.***.***]
4     8 ms     5 ms     5 ms  so-*-*-*-*.******-BB-****.verizon-gni.net     [***.***.***.***]
5    22 ms    31 ms    23 ms  P**-0-0.OTHERCITY-LCR-**.verizon-gni.net [***.***.***.***]
6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
7    24 ms    21 ms    21 ms  pool-***-**-***-***.othercity.fios.verizon.net [***.***.***.***]
```

As you can guess, the cities aren't far and the connection is all through Verizon fios. What I'm concerned about is the 6th line (which I haven't changed at all). Is that supposed to happen? Is there some way I can not have it time out and have a faster connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tracert sends a packet that will expire at each point in the path to the destination.  When a router receives a packet that has expired (TTL goes to zero) it should send an ICMP packet back to the source to let it know that the packet expired.

Tracert measures the time between the sending packet and the ICMP notification to work out the latency for each hop.

However, there is no guarantee that the ICMP packet will be sent.  Firewalls are generally configured to silently drop any packet targetted at them, and many routers are configured to not send ICMP packets in this scenario.

The hop you are seeing no response from is configured in this way.  It is perfectly normal and has no bearing on your connection speed.  Tracert would indicate an issue if you had no responses beyond a certain point in the path.  You are getting a 21ms response from the next hop after the one that doesn't respond, which is pretty good latency.

Comment: @JustinPearce Oooh, I hate it when that happens!  How far were you into your answer?

Comment: I had just started into an overview. Nothing of value was lost. :D